# Force a window to open at 100% width/height

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

RE-EDIT:

I am in the process of making a 1 page site. This is for a school and will only be accessed internally (like a page for different links that staff can quickly use to navigate to).

However sometimes staff have different sized windows open, when they open IE (it will auto re-direct them to my HTML page) is it possible to make sure they open it as 100% width and height? 
Thanks,

Nick

Comment: can you share the markup and css you have right now?

Comment: No problem see below:
http://jsfiddle.net/qL7zM/

Comment: It's only for Laptop and PC's in the school academy for staff. So there isn't going to be a large difference in res, it would just be nice to have it open at 100%

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can have width and height to take up 100% space but it is not easy to design a page like that for all resolutions. As you have to exapnd and shrink content both in height and width it becomes complex.better have a fixed width and have height according to the resolution(Again a problem with retina display). Here are some browser statistics- [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp).

you are concerned about your page on different resolutions of desktops and laptops. But the bigger problem would be mobiles and tablets as they do count for quite a lot of web-traffic.

Better way of handling the problem is to go with responsive design and target 2560×1600 and above 1366x768 for desktops and few mobile and tablet resolutions.

Here is a link for responsive design resourses- [resourses](http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

Liquid design isn't too difficult.

If you mean you want your page to open in a new tab or in the same already maximised tab, search for that; SO has that covered already.

Don't worry about height. Just make it fill the width and let the user scroll.